# Angular-bootstrap-ui with niceScroll issue in modal pop up

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, nicescroll

I am using niceScroll in angular-bootstrap-ui modal pop, In IE scroll bar is not working in modal pop up but in normal use its working fine. Thanks in advance.

```
 $('.ui-select-choices').niceScroll({
                    touchbehavior: true,
                    autohidemode: false
                });
```

**Issue in : In Modal pop (angular-bootstrap-ui)**
[image]

**Working fine: Normal use**
[image: normaluse]

Comment: probably some CSS styling is missing, compare both using dev tools in browser

Comment: @DmitriAlgazin css is same for both.